# Buscar NormalizedUserName do Identity .NET core nas razor pages

Tags: c#, .net, identity

Preciso exibir o nome do usuário na topbar. O razor como default fornece um objeto @User como padrão mas fornecendo poucas informações do usuário. O mesmo tem a propriedade nome porém traz o username em vez do nome do usuário. Seria possível de alguma forma buscar o NormalizedUserName pela View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voce tem a opção de injetar o UserManager no seu controller, e capturar as informações do usuario usando `_userManager.GetUserAsync(User);` e enviando para a sua view em um objeto ou preenchendo o seu ViewModel com essa informação e capturando na sua View.

```
private UserManager<User> _userManager;       
public SeuController(UserManager<User> userManager) {
_userManager = userManager;
    }

public IActionResult Get() {
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
// user.NormalizedUserName <-- passe isso pra sua view

}
```

A outra opção é injetando o `UserManager<User> userManager` com o `@inject` direto na view.

```
@inject UserManager<User> userManager
<div>
@{

var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

}
<span>
@user.NormalizedUserName 
</span>
<div>
```

Eu recomendaria usar a primeira opção na maioria dos casos.